# Primary keys in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, primary-key

I am using postgres and I  found this query to retrieve primary key of a table

```
SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod) AS data_type
FROM   pg_index i
JOIN   pg_attribute a ON a.attrelid = i.indrelid
                     AND a.attnum = ANY(i.indkey)
WHERE  i.indrelid = 'tablename'::regclass
AND    i.indisprimary;
```

I want to retrieve all primary keys and indexes in a databese. How to do this?

Thank you

Comment: Simply remove the condition `i.indrelid = 'tablename'::regclass`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thank you

Comment: You can retrieve this data from psql: `\di`. To check how it do this, just start psql with `-E` parameter.